# How do I install this module?

Tags: wysiwyg

I tried to install the [Wysiwyg](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module, but it doesn't work. I copied the folder to `/sites/all/`, but how do I enable it?

The instructions say:

> You need to install and configure an editor library also. Please see [this link](https://www.drupal.org/node/371459) for instructions.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you are confused about.  The instructions page seems pretty clear to me.  If you're having trouble with a specific step, please write what you are trying to do and what kind of error message you are getting or what kind of problem you are having.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is extremely vague. What doesn't work? What errors do you get? Have you actually tried to follow the very detailed instructions on the link you posted? If not, please follow those before asking here. If you have, what step of the instructions are you failing to understand?

Answer (score 5):

The module files are searched in specific directories, as evident in the [drupal_system_listing()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_system_listing/7) code. The directories where Drupal looks for modules are the following:

- profiles/$profile/modules, where `$profile` is the name of the currently enabled profile
- sites/all/modules
- $config/modules, where `$config` is the name of the directory containing the settings.php file currently used

If you copied the files in sites/all, then the module is not found because it is not in a directory where the modules are looked for; that would explain why you cannot enable the module.

The first step reported in the instructions is clearly the following one:

> Download, extract, and place Wysiwyg module in the modules folder **like any other Drupal module**.

(The emphasis is mine.)

The part you are quoting is not about the module, but the editor library that module should use.
Once you installed and enabled the module, you will be able to visit its configuration page (admin/config/content/wysiwyg), which will give you a list of libraries that module supports. Once you verify which one is compatible with your server, and you choose the one you want to use, you download the installation file following the link given in that page, and extract its content in sites/all/libraries/. Keep in mind the following notes give in the documentation page you linked.

- If the editor comes in a wrapper folder that equals its short-name, then you can put the entire wrapper folder straight into Wysiwyg's folder:
  /sites/all/libraries/[editorname]. Make sure that the resulting structure is NOT like /sites/all/libraries/[editorname]/[editorname] unless the settings page indicates otherwise.
- If the editor comes in a wrapper folder with additional characters (e.g. version number), then you can put the entire wrapper folder into the sites/all/libraries folder, but need to rename it to its short-name:
  /sites/all/libraries/[editorname]. Make sure that the resulting structure is NOT like /sites/all/libraries/[editorname]/[editorname-version].
- If the editor comes without a wrapper folder, then you need to create the editor's short-name folder yourself and copy the editor library files into that folder: /sites/all/libraries/[editorname].

If you correctly followed the instructions given from the module and its documentation, on admin/config/content/wysiwyg you will see that the editor library you copied will be reported as *installed*. If you don't see that, it means you copied the editor files in the wrong directory, or there are other errors (e.g. the version you installed is not compatible with the module).

Answer (score 0):

Move the module to `sites/all/modules/`. Then you can activate it under `index.php?q=admin/build/modules` (Drupal 6) or `index.php?q=admin/modules` (Drupal 7).